# How to hide {{ entry.title }} on a {structure} page but show it on a {structure}/{category-slug} page

Tags: templating, entry, category

Here's the breakdown:

» `structure` with two `categories`. Each category has +10 entries.

» Template is `structure` / `index.html` and `_entryview.html`

I'd like to show two links and a description of both categories on the `/structure/` URL.

However...

On the `/structure/index/` page, I'd like to show the `entries` for each category — all using the same `index` template.

So far I can pull the `{category.title}`s and the `{entry.title}` ... but it's the same on both pages (`structure/` and `structure/category`)

```
{% set categories = craft.categories.group('fellowsCat') %}

 <ul>
  {% nav category in craft.categories
    .group('fellowsCat')
    .limit(11)
    %}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.title }}</a>
      {% ifchildren %}
        <ul>
          {% children %}
        </ul>
      {% endifchildren %}
    </li>
  {% endnav %}
</ul> 

<ul>

{% set entries = craft.entries({
  section:  'fellows',
  relatedTo:  craft.categories('fellowsCat'),
})
%}


{# ___________________________
this is where things fall apart. 
If I'm on /structure/ I don't want to see entries. 
If I'm on /structure/category, I do. 
_____________________________
#}


{% if craft.categories is not null %}

  {% for entry in entries %}
    <li>  <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>

{% else %}
nothing to see
{% endif %}
```

I suspect there's something with the `{% if craft.categories is not null %}` line that would do the job, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

```
    {% set categories = craft.categories.group('fellowsCat') %}

 <ul>
  {% nav category in craft.categories
    .group('fellowsCat')
    %}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.title }}</a>
      {% ifchildren %}
        <ul>
          {% children %}
        </ul>
      {% endifchildren %}
    </li>
  {% endnav %}
</ul> 

<ul>


{# --- this is the key line here ---#}
{% if category is defined %}

{% set entries = craft.entries({
  relatedTo:  category,

})
%}

{% if craft.entries.relatedTo(category) %} 


      {% for entry in entries %}
        <li>  <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}
      </ul>

     {% else %} 
    nothing to see
     {% endif %} 
     {% endif %}
```

Comment: Just a side note `{% if craft.entries.relatedTo(category) %}` will always become true, no matter what. There is no legit way to go to the else part